# Get AD users’ manager and primary group that is associated with a user's manager

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to export users' manager data from AD to a csv file. I created a PowerShell script that Get users' manager data from AD which are as follows:

```
name, samaccountName, email address
```

and primary group that is associated with the manager and the user he managed.

I import a `user.csv` file in the code to retrieve the manager data and then export the data to `user_manager.csv`. My code doesn't work. Can you please help me?

Here  is import file, `user.csv`:

```
id        userid      groups  
-----------------------------
1         fiyx        f0302        
2         bise        acct     
3         misye       d4029        
4         suew        sales
```

Here's the code:

```
Import-Csv -Path "\tmp\user.csv" |
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.userid -Properties manager
$group  = Get-ADGroup -Identity $_.group.userid -Properties groups
 $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Manager' -Value $manager.Name
$manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Manager -Properties samaccountname, displayName, mail
 $_

} | Export-CSV -Path "C:\tmp\manager_user.csv" –NoTypeInformation
```

Below is the result that I want to see in  user_manager.csv:

```
userid    groups     manager       samaccountname     mail  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------   
fiyx      f0302      Brian Lee      brinle           brian.lee@creek.com
bise      acct       Susan Brisky   Susbri           susan.brisky@creek.com
misye     d4029      Mary Louname   marloun          mary.louname@creek.com
suew      sales      Wuson Tacos    wusta            wuson.tacos@creek.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Please always add the errors you're getting to the post, that way we don't have guess where the issues may occur. I didn't get the pipe at the end of the first line. Sometimes a loop helps to make scripts a bit more readable. This should work:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path "\tmp\user.csv"
foreach ($entry in $data){
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $entry.userid -Properties manager
    $manager = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Manager -Properties samaccountname, displayName, mail
    $entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Manager' -Value $manager.Name
    $entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'samaccountname' -Value $manager.samaccountname
    $entry | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'mail' -Value $manager.mail
}

$data | Export-CSV -Path "C:\tmp\manager_user.csv" –NoTypeInformation
```